# Session already started error in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a social website where users can register and see each other's posts. It works fine on my local server, but when I tried uploading to 000webhost.com the "session already started" error is shown. Is there a way to solve this problem ? Thanks!

Comment: Don't start the session twice. It gives you the file name where it happens and the line number. Magic.

Comment: I assume this is the "free" webhosting 000webhost offers. Remember, that "free" service uses PHP 5.2, which is WAY beyond [End of Life](http://php.net/eol.php)

Comment: I tried to provide my code but error occured "your code is not formatted"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code before starting session:

**For PHP >= 5.4.0**

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

**For PHP < 5.4.0**

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```